# condition probability

Tags: conditional-probability

There is 3 random variables, A, B and C
I know distribution P(C) and conditional distributions P(A|C) and P(B|C).
How to find P(A|B)?
I think it's necessary to integrate someone like this:

$$
P(A|B) = \int P((A|B)|C) dP(C)
$$

But how to find P((A|B)|C) ?

Comment: How do you define $P(A|C)$ and $P(B|C)$?

Comment: @Tom in details, random variable C is an expectation of A and B. A, B, and C are normal-distributed with given dispersions.

Comment: "how to find P((A|B)|C)" Rather, the question would be how to *define* P((A|B)|C) (this does not exist).

Comment: "I know distribution P(C) and conditional distributions P(A|C) and P(B|C). How to find P(A|B)?" The data (P(C), P(A|C) and P(B|C)) does not determine P(A|B).

Comment: @Tom "How do you define P(A|C) and P(B|C)?" Funny that you would ask because, once one realized that A, B and C are (rather illogically) random variables, this is the only part of the question that causes *no* problem.

Comment: @Did I suppose it isn't uncommon that if $\nu$ is a measure and $f$ is measurable, you can define $\nu(f) = \int f \,d\nu$.. is that what's happening here? $P(A\mid C) = E_P[A \mid C]$?

Comment: @Tom My guess is that when X and Y are random variables, the OP writes P(X|Y) for the conditional distribution of X conditioned on Y... but do not start me again on the topic of horrendous notations. :-)